# Set min-width equal to height?

Tags: css

It's easy enough to set an element's height depending on its width using tricks such as setting `margin-top: AR%`, with AR being the aspect ratio of the element.

However, I'd like to do something the other way around.

Namely, I'd like to set the element's `min-width` to be equal to the element's `height`, which may be dynamic based on content.

If this isn't possible, that's okay - it's only needed for user-generated content, since the cases where I use it have a static and known height! It's fairly minor, but if it can be done then that'd be great.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The easiest way would be with a bit of JavaScript

Comment: @Thomas Yes. CSS only. If it's only possible with JavaScript then it's not worth it here. This is why I only tagged with [tag:css] ;)